# How to give distance between the circles in d3

Tags: d3.js

I was able to create circles with d3 but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to add space between them?

```
var myCircle= [20, 10, 50, 80, 40];
var height = 500
var width = 500


var mychart = d3.select('#chartD').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .selectAll('circle')
              .data(myCircle)
              .enter()
              .append('circle')
              .attr("cx", function (d) { return d; })
              .attr("cy", function (d) { return d; })
              .attr("r", function (d) {
                return d;
              })
              .style("fill", '#f4f4f4')

}
```

Comment: Read https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/ by Mike Bostock, test `.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return i * 100 + 30; })` and adjust the values

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful.